# Java 2D Array Search Not Working

Tags: java, arrays

This program is supposed to return the location of a piece on a board.The board  is being represented as a 2D array. The loop simply cycles through the columns and then if the piece is still not found it goes to the next row. However,only the `[-1,-1]` array is being returned( no pieces are being found). I have not been able to find the error on my own, so any help

```
public int[] pieceFinder(int piece) {

    int[][] board={{43,44,45,50,47,48,49},
                   {36,37,38,39,40,41,42},
                   {29,30,31,32,33,34,35},
                   {22,23,24,25,26,27,28},
                   {15,16,17,18,19,20,21},
                   {8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
                   {1,2,3,50,5,6,7}};    

    int row=0;  
    boolean found=false;
    int[] location={-1,-1} ;  

    for(int column=0;found==true;column++) {
        if(board[row][column]==piece) {
            found=true ;
            location[0]=row; 
            location[1]=column;
        }

        else if(column==6) {
            if(row==6) { 
                break;
            }

        else {
            row++;
        }
    } 
    return location;
}
```

Comment: Think carefully about the loop condition. Double-check with your book what it means.

Answer (score 4):

```
boolean found=false;
for(int column=0;found==true;column++){
```

As you can see found is false. And for loop checks for true value for found. It will never enter the loop. That's why locations gets returned as it is.